# SQL Query with Left Join slows down

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Cleaning up some mess in a query that was written couple of years ago and I noticed that the below query is the cause of slowing down the result. I tried to search for alternatives but was not too successful.

```
WITH cat
     AS (SELECT main.category_id main_id,
                main.description main_desc,
                sub1.category_id sub1_id,
                sub1.description sub1_desc,
                sub2.category_id sub2_id,
                sub2.description sub2_desc,
                sub3.category_id sub3_id,
                sub3.description sub3_desc,
                NVL (
                   NVL (NVL (sub3.category_id, sub2.category_id),
                        sub1.category_id),
                   main.category_id)
                   lowest
           FROM iod.sr_category main
                -- We need to insert a temporary null row and include it in the join so the categories which are not leaves are also included
                LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT category_id, description, parent_id
                   FROM iod.sr_category
                 UNION
                 SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
                   FROM DUAL) sub1
                   ON (   main.category_id = sub1.parent_id
                       OR sub1.category_id IS NULL)
                LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT category_id, description, parent_id
                   FROM iod.sr_category
                 UNION
                 SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
                   FROM DUAL) sub2
                   ON (   sub1.category_id = sub2.parent_id
                       OR sub2.category_id IS NULL)
                LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT category_id, description, parent_id
                   FROM iod.sr_category
                 UNION
                 SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
                   FROM DUAL) sub3
                   ON (   sub2.category_id = sub3.parent_id
                       OR sub3.category_id IS NULL)
          WHERE     main.parent_id IS NULL
                AND (main.category_id IN ( :main_category))
                AND (   NVL ( :sub_category1, 0) = 0
                     OR sub1.category_id = :sub_category1)
                AND (   NVL ( :sub_category2, 0) = 0
                     OR sub2.category_id = :sub_category2)
                AND (   NVL ( :sub_category3, 0) = 0
                     OR sub3.category_id = :sub_category3))
  SELECT r.sector_report_id,
         r.created_date report_created_date --, nvl(f.sch_dep_date_local_port, f.sch_dep_date_gmt) report_search_date
                                           ,
         c.main_desc,
         c.sub1_desc,
         c.sub2_desc,
         c.sub3_desc,
         p.problem_type_code,
         p.description,
         e.first_name,
         e.last_name,
         e.employee_id,
         cl.description class,
         ROW_NUMBER ()
         OVER (PARTITION BY r.sector_report_id, cl.class_id
               ORDER BY q.question_id)
            question_num,
         q.label question,
         q.data_type,
         NVL (
            pa.answer,
            NVL (
               a.VALUE,
               NVL (a.free_text,
                    NVL (a.hours || ':' || a.minutes, 'NO ANSWER'))))
            answer,
         f.arln_code,
         f.flight_number,
         f.sch_dep_date_gmt,
         f.sch_dep_date_local_port,
         f.sch_dep_apt,
         f.sch_arv_apt,
         f.tail_number,
         f.fleet_code,
         LISTAGG (
               e_cmt.first_name
            || ' '
            || e_cmt.last_name
            || ' '
            || cmt.created_date
            || ':'
            || cmt.comment_text,
            ' ' || CHR (10))
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cmt.created_date)
            comments,
         (NVL ( (SELECT COUNT (*)
                   FROM iod.sr_photograph p
                  WHERE p.sector_report_id = r.sector_report_id),
               0))
            AS photo
    FROM iod.sr_sector_report r
         JOIN cat c ON c.lowest = r.category_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.sr_problem_type p
            ON p.problem_type_id = r.problem_type_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.ops_flight_leg f
            ON f.ops_flight_leg_id = r.ops_flight_leg_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.employee e ON e.employee_id = r.employee_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.sr_class_sector_report csr
            ON csr.sector_report_id = r.sector_report_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.sr_class cl ON cl.class_id = csr.class_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.sr_answer a ON a.sector_report_id = r.sector_report_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.sr_predefined_answer pa
            ON pa.predefined_answer_id = a.predefined_answer_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.sr_question q ON q.question_id = a.question_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.sr_comment cmt
            ON cmt.sector_report_id = r.sector_report_id
         LEFT JOIN iod.employee e_cmt ON e_cmt.employee_id = cmt.employee_id
   WHERE     (NVL ( :problem_type, 0) = 0 OR p.problem_type_id = :problem_type)
         AND TRUNC (f.sch_dep_date_local_port) BETWEEN :from_date AND :TO_DATE
         --and cast(nvl(f.sch_dep_date_local_port, f.sch_dep_date_gmt) as date) between  :from_date and :to_date
         AND (--nvl(:station_from, ' ') = ' ' or
              f.sch_dep_apt IN ( :station_from))
         AND (--nvl(:station_to, ' ') = ' ' or
              f.sch_arv_apt IN ( :station_to))
GROUP BY r.sector_report_id,
         r.created_date,
         c.main_desc,
         c.sub1_desc,
         c.sub2_desc,
         c.sub3_desc,
         p.problem_type_code,
         p.description,
         e.first_name,
         e.last_name,
         e.employee_id,
         cl.description,
         cl.class_id,
         q.label,
         q.data_type,
         q.question_id,
         NVL (
            pa.answer,
            NVL (
               a.VALUE,
               NVL (a.free_text,
                    NVL (a.hours || ':' || a.minutes, 'NO ANSWER')))),
         f.arln_code,
         f.flight_number,
         f.sch_dep_date_gmt,
         f.sch_dep_date_local_port,
         f.sch_dep_apt,
         f.sch_arv_apt,
         f.tail_number,
         f.fleet_code
ORDER BY TRUNC (f.sch_dep_date_local_port) ASC
```

so the part

```
subx.category_id = suby.parent_id OR suby.category_id is null
```

slows down the query. Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies. Submitted the question in a rush and hence took up the recommended tags. :)

Comment: That then begs the question of why Stack Overflow doesn't do a better job.  Identifying this as Oracle is pretty easy.

Comment: True that. I can raise a whole new question for word recognition algorithms and get stackoverflow's attention. :)

Comment: Do you absolutely need those `NULL` placeholder records?

Comment: Yes Tim. I need it. I was thinking on whether I can use Cases and solve the problem?

Comment: Can you post a SQL Monitor report or execution plan?

Comment: It's possible that you could get some performance enhancements out of pivoting the sr_category data, rather than using three left joins, but without more information such as sample input data and expected output, it's difficult to say. And could all three bind variables be null?

Answer (score 0):

Without an explain plan or an understanding of the business logic being implemented all we can do is guess. But this does seem like a scenario where sub-query factoring could help:

```
with sub as (
   SELECT category_id, description, parent_id FROM sr_category
   UNION
   SELECT null, null, null FROM DUAL)  
select 
     ....
from 
     ....
LEFT JOIN sub sub1
  ON (main.category_id = sub1.parent_id OR sub1.category_id is null)

  LEFT JOIN sub sub2
  ON (sub1.category_id = sub2.parent_id OR sub2.category_id is null)

  LEFT JOIN sub sub3
  ON (sub2.category_id = sub3.parent_id OR sub3.category_id is null)

  WHERE main.parent_id is null
  AND (main.category_id IN (:main_category))
  AND (nvl(:sub_category1, 0) = 0 OR sub1.category_id = :sub_category1)
  AND (nvl(:sub_category2, 0) = 0 OR sub2.category_id = :sub_category2)
  AND (nvl(:sub_category3, 0) = 0 OR sub3.category_id = :sub_category3))
```

The WITH clause is covered in the Oracle SQL documentation. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2077142)

Comment: Hi I just updated the question with the entire query. Would it help? :)